# How to save Data to DB where one column has an array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to save some values to the database, the **awb_no** column as an array and I want to attach the other value to each of the **awb_no** from the array, thanks.

My code:

```
public function bulkSelection($status)
    {
        $this->destinationId = Waybills::whereIn('id', $this->selectedRows)->pluck('destination_id');
        // dd($destinationId);
        $results = Waybills::whereIn('id', $this->selectedRows)->pluck('awb_no');

        $history = new History();

            
            $history->awb_no = $results;
            $history->status_id = $status;
            $history->state_id = $this->destinationId;
            $history->status_date = date('Y-m-d');
            $history->created_by = auth()->user()->id;

            $history->save();

        session()->flash('message', 'Status updated successfully!');
        return redirect('/admin/awbs/');
}
```

I keep getting this error in the browser

**Incorrect integer value: '[2,3,2]' for column `testapp`.`histories`.`state_id` at row 1**

insert into `histories` (`awb_no`,
`status_id`,
`state_id`,
`status_date`,
`created_by`,
`updated_at`,
`created_at`) values
(["0099123","S2428715482","S4009921375"],
2,
[2,3,2],
2022-10-19,
1,
2022-10-19 16:00:09,
2022-10-19 16:00:09)

[image: screenshot here]

Comment: `$this->destinationId;` is an array, `[2, 3, 2]`; that is not valid for `state_id`, which is an `integer` column (expects a single number). Is there something unclear about your error message here? It's telling you precisely that...

Comment: I see that, I know there is a way of doing this properly with foreach loop, but I cant seem to figure that out

Answer (score 0):

You've nailed in the comments; you would need to use a `foreach()` loop here:

```
foreach($this->destinationId->unique() as $stateId) {
  $history = new History();

  $history->awb_no = $results;
  $history->status_id = $status;
  $history->state_id = $stateId;
  $history->status_date = date('Y-m-d');
  $history->created_by = auth()->user()->id;

  $history->save();
}
```

This will create 2 `History` records in the database, one for each **unique** `$stateId` (your array was `[2, 3, 2]`, with `2` being duplicated)

Edit: If you want to insert a `History` model for each `->pluck('destination_id')`, including the duplicated `2`, then simply omit the `->unique()`:

```
foreach($this->destinationId as $stateId) {
  // Same code inside
}
```

Edit: If you're calling `->pluck('destination_id')`, it doesn't make sense to use that as `state_id`, especially if you have SQL-level constraints:

```
$this->destinationId = Waybills::whereIn('id', $this->selectedRows)->pluck('destination_id');

foreach($this->destinationId as $stateId) {
  $history = new History();

  $history->awb_no = $results;
  $history->status_id = $status;
  $history->destination_id = $stateId;
  $history->status_date = date('Y-m-d');
  $history->created_by = auth()->user()->id;

  $history->save();
}
```

Comment: Tried the about code, getting the error below.                                                 
 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`courierapp`.`histories`, CONSTRAINT `histories_state_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`state_id`) REFERENCES `states`

Comment: the value 2 is actually needed/correct not really a case of duplication

Comment: No, your error is saying that `state_id` 2 or 3 fails a constraint you have in place on the `histories` table. How many rows do you get back when you run `SELECT * FROM states WHERE id IN (2, 3)`? If you don't get exactly 2, then there's your issue.

Comment: You're doing `->pluck('destination_id')`, which references `waybills.destination_id`,  then using those as `state_id` on `histories`, which doesn't seem related to your `states` table at all. Did you maybe mean `->pluck('state_id')`?

Comment: Also, with all due respect, this is the 2nd time you've posted a SQL-level error without seeming to make an attempt to fix it. Please try to do some debugging on your end before posting updates. If you're not familiar with an error, you'll have to check your SQL Engine (MySQL, Postgres, etc.) Documentation

Comment: changed this line to  $history->destination_id = $this->destinationId;  still having errors

Comment: That _would_ be the same error as before; `$this->destinationId` would be an array. You need to loop it... Why are we back to your first issue though? Again, with all due respect, you don't seem to have a grasp of the basics here, and I don't have the time to teach you all of that. Please so some debugging on your end, learn the difference between an array of integers and a single integer, how to iterate an array, etc.

Comment: ok, thanks for your time, I will carefully go through the code again. But this is am try to do [link]https://imgur.com/oEHCMSk

Comment: Then again, `foreach ($this->destinationId as $destinationId)`, followed by `$history->destinationId;`, and the rest of the code in my answer should work. But if you don't know the basics of PHP's syntax, and Laravel's usage, you should figure that out first before attempting stuff like this. I'll edit my answer, but beyond that, I have to just say best of luck!